# Angular Material table dataSource not being rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

I can get the dataSource2 (example from angular library) to show correctly,
but the dataSource variable (my datasource) does not render.

I am not sure why this is the case. I have made both data sources look similar, and the way I use the angular material library is also similar. I need some input; is it the way Material library works?

[See image - Message on dataSource not rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3EVb.png)

**My .ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BackendcallingService } from './../backendcalling.service';
import { AvailableRolesEntity, RoleFunctionsEntity, ChildRolesEntity } from 'src/models/AvailableRoles.model';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-roles',
  templateUrl: './roles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./roles.component.css']
})
export class RolesComponent implements OnInit {


  jsondata: any;
  jsonifiedrole: any;
  availableRoles: any;
  jsonifiedavailableRoles: any[];

  dataSource: any = [];
  dataSource2: any =[];

displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol']; // columns for example dataSource2
        columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'priority', 'editUrl', 'active', 'createdId'];  // columns for my dataSource

  ELEMENT_DATA: any[] = [
    { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
    { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
    { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
    { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  ];

  svc: any;
  http: any;

  response: any;



  constructor(http: HttpClient, svc: BackendcallingService) {
    this.http = http;
    this.svc = svc;

  }

  ngOnInit() {




    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/epsdk-app-os/get_role?role_id=undefined')
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.response = response;

        this.jsondata = (JSON.parse(response.data));
        this.role = this.jsondata.role;
        this.jsonifiedrole = JSON.parse(this.role);

        this.availableRoles = this.jsondata.availableRoles;
        this.jsonifiedavailableRoles = JSON.parse(this.availableRoles);


        this.dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.ELEMENT_DATA); // example data source
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.jsonifiedavailableRoles); //my datasource

        console.log(this.jsondata);
        console.log(this.role);
        console.log(this.jsonifiedrole);
        console.log(this.availableRoles);
        console.log(this.jsonifiedavailableRoles);

      })

  }

}
```

The jsonifiedavailableRoles looks like this. I don't know how it is different from ELEMENT_DATA which does get rendered as dataSource2

[See image - jsonifiedavailableRoles looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMeCv.png)

**My .html file**

```
<div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource2" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div>
  <br>

  <table> mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="priority">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Priority </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.priority}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="editUrl">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edit </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.editUrl}} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="active">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active? </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.active}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="createdId">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdId}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
```

Comment: Your `jsonifiedavailableRoles`  is not conforming to the displayedColumns

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @dileepkumarjami Still does not work. See the new change I made in the  question code as advised by you and Ramesh   
I changed  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'priority', 'editUrl', 'active', 'createdId'];

Answer (score 0):

`columnsToDisplay` should match to your html markup.

```
columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'priority', 'editUrl', 'active', 'createdId'];  // columns for my dataSource

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
```

Comment: I made the change. Still the same error. I made the change in the  question code as advised by you

Answer (score 0):

Also change the html,

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
```

Also  in your get() inside ngOnInit, pass `this.jsonifiedavailableRoles`

```
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.jsonifiedavailableRoles);
```

Comment: Same error.

Made this change:  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.jsonifiedavailableRoles);

Why extra semicolon at the end of columnsToDisplay?  (But does not work even with change)
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>

this.jsonifiedavailableRoles is already an Array as shown in the console screenshot in the question. Not sure copying to another array would work.
Also that array itself consists of complex json object in it

Not using all properties should not be the problem.

Comment: Did you change the `columnstodisplay`?

Comment: edited my response. Yes I made changes to  columnsToDisplay

Comment: What I meant is `*matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"`

Comment: Yes, it has always been *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay".  
*matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"  is for dataSource2